# AVAudioPlayer returns nil at random

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad, avaudioplayer

I have the following lines in my code:

```
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[soundString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."]objectAtIndex:0] ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL *soundURL_ = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
av_player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL_ error:nil];
```

These lines are in a class calles `AnimatableObject` which i use about 10 to 30 times in one `ViewController`.

It all works perfectly the first few times the `ViewControllers` get initialized and loaded. But after switching the `ViewControllers` some time my app crashes because the following line (which had worked all the times before) returns nil right now.

```
av_player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL_ error:nil];
```

I checked if soundPath or soundURL_ are nil. But they are ok. Exactly the same value like all the times before when it worked.

So now I ask myself how can it happen, that it works a lot of times and than returns nil?
In the same app, without closing and starting it again. And all I do is switching between viewControllers.
I first thought it is an memory issue, but i don't get any memory warnings.

I really have no idea why this is happening.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thx in advance,
Maverick.

--------Edit--------

I now found out that i get the following error:

```
ImageIO: CGImageRead_mapData 'open' failed '/var/mobile/Applications/F3186E1A-BBC2-47A6-8EF6-90F73C9BD566/huckla_zoo.app/Weiter.png'
error = 24 (Too many open files)
```

so i realize that i cannot open a soundfile when i get this error. 
Only thing i wonder now is:
How can i close file-handles?
I don't load the images via `[UIImage imageNamed:]` but with

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filename];
```

I also have implemented a MutableDictionary as image cache which gets emptied, when memory issues occur.
Is there any other option for me to close my file-handles?

Comment: from documentation of initWithContentsOfURL:error: method return value: "If nil, the error parameter contains a code that describes the problem.", instead of passing nil pass NSError object and see what error you get, I would check once again soundPath and soundURL_ if they aren't nil

Comment: ok, i updated the question since i know now what causes the crash. thx to alhcr.

Answer (score 2):

TRY THIS,

NSString* URL = [YOUR_URL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: You're really awesome, my app name had spaces in it, and this resolved my issue. 1 Up after three years! Also this problem is for iOS 7 ...

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it sounds like you've opened a lot of files, and forgotten to close them. Are you releasing file objects when you're done? How many files are you working with?

Comment: yes i do have a lot of files open. Where is the best place to release them? in the dealloc of the AnimatableObject which containes the file?
I have about 10 to 30 Objects of type AnimatableObject per ViewController. Each AnimatableObject can contain on UIImage and one or more AVAudioPlayers. The AnimatableObjects are IBOutlets, so i set them to nil in the viewDidUnload of the ViewController. Do I have to release all Variables contained in AnimatableObject in the dealloc method?